# How to Connect two Generic Handler c# asp.net Generic_Handler.ashx and Search.ashx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

How to Connect two Generic Handler c# asp.net  Generic_Handler.ashx  and Search.ashx
                        This is my two handlers if it is possible to connect two handlers in ASP.Net
                        Please Help any one**

**Generic_Handler.ashx**

```
        <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Generic_Handler" %>

         using System;
         using System.Web;
         using System.Data.SqlClient;
         using System.Configuration;

         public class Generic_Handler : IHttpHandler 
         {
               public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
               {
                    string id = context.Request.QueryString["ID"];
                    byte[] bytes;
                    string FileType;
                    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
                    {
                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                        {
                             cmd.CommandText = "select Video, FileType from TBL_YouTube where ID=@ID";
                             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", id);
                             cmd.Connection = con;
                             con.Open();
                             SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                             sdr.Read();
                             bytes = (byte[])sdr["Video"];
                             FileType = sdr["FileType"].ToString();
                             con.Close();
                          }
                    }
                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.Buffer = true;
                    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; ID=" + id);
                    context.Response.ContentType = FileType;
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
                    context.Response.End();
              }

             public bool IsReusable
             {
                    get 
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
            }

         }
```

**Search.ashx**

```
            <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Search" %>

            using System;
            using System.Web;
            using System.Data.SqlClient;
            using System.Text;

            public class Search : IHttpHandler 
            {

                public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
                {
                      //context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                      //context.Response.Write("Hello World");
                        string searchText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Videos;Integrated Security=True");
                        con.Open();
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select FileName from TBL_YouTube where FileName Like @Search + '%'", con);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", searchText);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (dr.Read())
                            {
                                 sb.Append(string.Format("{0},{1}", dr["FileName"], Environment.NewLine));
                            }
                         }
                         con.Close();
                         context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
                }

                 public bool IsReusable 
                 {
                      get 
                      {
                          return false;
                      }
                 }

           }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connect two handlers"? Do you mean you want to share some code between them?

Comment: In this "Generic_Handler. Ashx" I am retrieving the video from the database, display in list view And In "Search. Ashx" I am using for "Text Box Auto search" for this handler I am retrieving the "Video Name" in Text Box form database and it should play by clicking the search file name